# StarCraft 2 leaver's resources

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2, after a player drops/leaves on a team, the resources *already gathered* by that player is split and distributed among allies that remain.  But will the resources (mineral/gas) that are continually being gathered be split amongst allies?

Comment: +1, I wondered this myself. My team once fought a 3v3 where 2 opponents dropped immediately. We wondered if it was intentional, since the remaining player built a large force very quickly with all the resources.

Comment: @Wikwocket there are probably some people who do this on purpose, and some to whom it happens by accident.  Either way, don't get complacent (see my answer for more)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, resources gathered will be continuously split among allies.

Also you can control his units after he leaves, train units in his building, and build new buildings in his base using his workers.

Comment: Do units you build from his buildings count towards your food-supply? (What about units that were queued when he left? :)

Comment: @BlueRaja - that sounds like a new question :D

Comment: Units built from his buildings count toward his food supply, not yours. Because of this - be careful of getting your dropped teammate supply blocked if you want to keep using their buildings.

Comment: Just to add some important information. All the resources the dropped player continues to harvest are shared with allies. And producing any units/buildings with the dropped player requires your own resources, but does not use your own food count.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  This is sometimes used to perform turbo cheese rushes.  Normally, you are not allowed to transfer resources to your allies until several minutes into the game.  Dropping out is a way around this.  When the ally drops out of a game, all their starting resources plus all minerals gathered by their workers get transferred to the remaining player(s).  If I recall properly, a 6 pool can get the initial 6 lings out 25 game seconds faster this way, and have the speed upgrade and plenty of lings pumping faster than normal.

If you are in a team game and see one or more opponents drop out immediately, but the other player doesn't surrender, be prepared to defend an early rush, then immediately counterattack to kill the empty bases of the dropped players.  Do not relax and think "oh this will be an easy 2v1" until you've killed off the extra base.  The single player using two players' minerals has certain advantages over the remaining team, like the initial head start in minerals, and only having to build tech buildings once.  This advantage wanes over time, but can be used to eke out a victory over an unprepared team.